# Service worker failed to fetch OGG files in Chrome for Android and other webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am developing a progressive web app and I had a problem with the service worker but under very specific conditions. I searched but no answer can solve my problem.

I saw the question [Chrome install Service Worker addAll failed to fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865552/chrome-install-service-worker-addall-failed-to-fetch) but I think that is not my problem because my SW fails to fetch only OGG files.

This is the event and problem:

1. The app cache png and ogg files.
2. Open with network access in desktop or Android mobile and both works very well, sounds and images.
3. Open offline in desktop and the same, sounds and images work well.
4. Open offline in mobile with Firefox, sounds and images work well.
5. Open offline in mobile with Chrome 67.0.3396.87 on Android or with Opera, or other webkit browser and images work well but sounds **fail**.
6. If I close and reopen the web immediately the cache store only the played sounds, only Chrome (or activate offline option in Network tab in the developer tools). That suggesting me that in Chrome the sounds only are cached after using them. But after a while, I reopen and happens the same as point 5. No sounds, perfect images, scripts and css.

I got the following errors and details:

[Description in the console, using remote debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKP5o.png)

[Network tab information for Chrome using remote debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCxJa.png)

This is my service worker (this is a new topic for me):

```js
//13jul2018_8pm
var dataCacheName = 'name-pwa';
var cacheName = 'name-pwa';
var filesToCache = [
    '/',
    'manifest.json',
    'index.html',
    'main.js',
    'img/img1.png',
    'img/img2.png',
    'img/spellHeal_8.png',
    'img/heal.png',
    'ogg/ogg1.ogg',
    'ogg/ogg2.ogg',
    'ogg/heal.ogg'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName && key !== dataCacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

I tried to fix it changing the mode of using the ogg files:
a. In a `<audio>` element
b. Using Javascript injection with `audio = new Audio`
I change the entire SW with some prebuild to check if this is the problem, but it did not fix the problem.

Maybe someone has this problem and a way to solve it?

Thanks in advance, any suggestion is welcomed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things I detected that Chrome, in both Android and Desktop is especially sensitive to lack of caching a promise problem, but this problem is only effective in my app when fetching a OGG (or other audio files) when offline. As posted in my question, PNG files work marvelously.

I solved finally the problem by modifying the fetch event of my service worker, including clone the request as suggested in Google help webpage. I am sharing the solution if someone has the same problem. Weird behavior in Google Chrome.

Here is the modified fetch event.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(caches.match(e.request)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request)
        .then(function (resp){
          return caches.open(cacheName)
            .then(function(cache){
              cache.put(e.request, resp.clone());
              return resp;
          })
        }).catch(function(event){
          console.log('[Service Worker] Error fetching data!');
        })
      })
  );
});
```