# Iterator getter is not callable

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to download a json file and cache it, but I get a error.
Here is the code:

```
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        // With the cache opened, load a JSON file containing an array of files to be cached
        return fetch('resource').then(function(response) {
          // Once the contents are loaded, convert the raw text to a JavaScript object
          return response.json();
        }).then(function(files) {
          // Use cache.addAll just as you would a hardcoded array of items
          console.log('[install] Adding files from JSON file: ', files);
          return cache.addAll(files);
        });
      })
      .then(function() {
        // Message to simply show the lifecycle flow
        console.log(
          '[install] All required resources have been cached;',
          'the Service Worker was successfully installed!'
        );

        // Force activation
        return self.skipWaiting();
      })
  );
```

mysw.js:42 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Iterator getter is not callable.

cache.addAll(files); seems to making problems.

Comment: What type are you passing as `files`.. according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/addAll) it needs to be (and I quote) "An array of string URLs that you want to be fetched and added to the cache."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rathen then :

```
cache.addAll(files);
```

Use :

```
files.map((url) => {
    return cache.add(url);
});
```

because the **cache.addAll(files)** will **fail** when 1 of the file is not accessible (HTTP 400,401 etc, also 5XX and 3XX sometimes) to avoid failing all when 1 fail use individual catch statement in a map loop .

Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46865785/6375501